# String attributes in .arff file for LibSVM, Weka.

Tags: weka, libsvm

I'm trying to use LibSVM in Weka. In my .arff dataset I have @attribute attr1 String. But when I checked the LibSVM capabilities I figured out LibSVM doesn't support String attributes. Is there any way to convert the string to numeric value , so I can keep it in my data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it really is a string (and not a nominal value), you can use [StringToWordVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html)

> Converts String attributes into a set of attributes representing word occurrence (depending on the tokenizer) information from the text contained in the strings. The set of words (attributes) is determined by the first batch filtered (typically training data).

It really depends on what you want to get out of the String. If it is not "normal" text, but something like DNA sequences, you'd need something completely different.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to drop the textual feature from my training model. But anyway thanks

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of string attribute was it? I'm curious

Comment: I'm working on open source projects, I wanted to use bug description from bug tracking system as one of the train model's feature :)

Comment: Then the StringToWord vector could've done the trick. Alternatively, you could build a list of important terms by hand and extract them, e.g., whether the term 'Linux' is contained or not as a binary feature